# XFS_Quota - Issue for group

Tags: linux, centos, quota, xfs

I set xfs_quota limit to group id. But hard/soft limit doesn't take effect. Only it works if I set the quota limit to users.

group name : itshare

username : testuser

"testuser" mapped to group "itshare"

If you see the below steps, I have set soft limit to 3MB and hard limit to 4MB for the group itshare.

but user "testuser" can upload the file more than the limit specified.

```
[root@srv1 ~]#xfs_quota -x -c 'limit -g bsoft=3m bhard=4m itshare'  /home

[root@srv1 ~]# xfs_quota -x -c 'report -h ' /home
User quota on /home (/dev/mapper/centos-home)
                        Blocks              
User ID      Used   Soft   Hard Warn/Grace   
---------- --------------------------------- 
root       391.8M      0      0  00 [------]
testuser       5.7M     0     0  00 [-none-]


Group quota on /home (/dev/mapper/centos-home)
                        Blocks              
Group ID     Used   Soft   Hard Warn/Grace   
---------- --------------------------------- 
root       391.8M      0      0  00 [------]
testuser       5.7M      0      0  00 [------]
itshare         0     3M     4M  00 [------]
[root@srv1 ~]#

[root@srv1 ~]# id testuser
uid=1000(testuser) gid=1000(testuser) groups=1000(testuser),1003(itshare)
[root@srv1 ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

May it be the case that the files are written using the "testuser" group instead of "itshare", and for that reason the xfs quota does not apply as "space used by that group"? 
Just speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `xfs_quota` is only valid for Primary Group. It wont work for Secondary Group (in your case group: `itshare`).

You need Project Quota as workaround.

1. Mount your disk/partition with `prjquota` option:

   ```
   # mount -o rw,remount,prjquota /home
   # mount | grep home
   ```

   Make sure `prjquota` option is displayed.
2. Create `itshare` dir:

   ```
   # mkdir /home/itshare
   # chown -R testuser:itshare /home/itshare
   # chmod -R g+rwx /home/itshare
   ```
3. Create Project ID (can be any numerical value)

   ```
   # echo "11:/home/itshare" >> /etc/projects
   # echo "itshare:11" >> /etc/projid
   ```
4. Initialize project directory

   ```
   # xfs_quota -x -c 'project -s itshare' /home
   ```
5. Configure quotas for projects with initialized directories:

   ```
   # xfs_quota -x -c 'limit -p bsoft=3m bhard=4m itshare' /home
   ```
6. Test

Reference:

[1] https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_file_systems/assembly_limiting-storage-space-usage-on-xfs-with-quotas_managing-file-systems